# Python Directory Print File Names Only

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to write a program that will print out all of bmp files' file names inside the entire folder (minus the entire directory), but so far all of the codes I have experimented prints out not just the file name but also the directory with folder names attached. Please tell me how to fix this issue. Below are the two codes I have experimented with:

Code 1:

```
import glob, os
```

path = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\y\z"

for bmp_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.bmp')):
    print (bmp_file)

In this code it prints: C:\Users\x\Desktop\y\z\file name, when all I want is file name

Code 2:

```
import os.path, sys
```

path = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\y\z"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for item in dirs:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, item)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):

f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
    if e.endswith('.bmp'):
        print (fullpath)</pre></code>

In this code it prints C:\Users\x\Desktop\y\z\file name just like code 1 but all I want is file name. Thanks! Any helps or hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: but... `print (fullpath)` => `print (item)` ... also why splitting the full path, and use endswith on the extension?? just test equality

Comment: for the first code, `print (os.path.basename(bmp_file))`

Comment: Thanks man! Tried it out and it works!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change your last line of code:

From :

```
print (fullpath)
```

To:

```
print (fullpath[:-4])
```